# Angular: PrimeNG Organization Chart not rendering the chart properly

Tags: angular, user-interface, frontend, primeng, angular9

I have implemented an organization chart by PrimeNG as per my requirement. My data from the `TreeNode` type array is getting rendered in UI properly but the design is not.
Below is my code:

**app.module.ts**

```
import {OrganizationChartModule} from 'primeng/organizationchart';
imports: [ OrganizationChartModule ]
```

**thankyou.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { ApplicationService } from '../service-application/application.service';
import {TreeNode} from 'primeng/api';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-thankyou',
  templateUrl: './thankyou.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./thankyou.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})

export class ThankyouComponent implements OnInit {

  totObtainedMarks: number = 0;
  totTotalMarks: number = 0;
  marks: TreeNode[];
  constructor(public appService: ApplicationService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    let result = [];
    for(let i of this.appService.result) {
      let mark: any;
      this.totObtainedMarks += i.obtainedMarks;
      this.totTotalMarks += i.totalMarks;
      mark = {
        label: i.questionCategory + ': ' + i.obtainedMarks.toString() + '/' + this.totTotalMarks.toString()
      };
      result.push(mark);
    }
    this.marks = [{
      label: 'Total: ' + this.totObtainedMarks.toString() + '/' + this.totTotalMarks.toString(),
      children: result
    }];
  }
}
```

**thankyou.component.html**

`<p-organizationChart [value]="marks"></p-organizationChart>`

The view I am getting:
[image: view]

I followed the official documentation for creating this but still not able to understand what's the problem.
Please help me out.

Comment: make sure `ThankyouComponent` is declared within app.module, also not other module, do you see any console errors ?

Comment: no console error and the component is declared and what does "also not other module" means ?

Comment: I mean "and not any other module" sorry also is a mistake, as long as `ThankYouComponent" is declared within app.moduel, it looks fine for me.

Comment: yup that's why am confused. Only the styling is not rendered :(

Comment: @Avishek Did you add the needed CSS references for any PrimeNG component?

Comment: @Roy needed CSS means ? for this chart in the documentation no css was written

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I check out the most basic example of a organisational chart from PrimeNG on StackBlitz and look into the `angular.json`, some style references need to be added in order to make it work.

### **[StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-organizationchart-demo-exev2v?file=angular.json) without styles**

[image: StackBlitz example without styles]
You can clearly see, that something is not right, and it looks quite the same as your problem.

### **StackBlitz example with styles in** `angular.json`

When adding (or not commenting out) these CSS references lines in the `angular.json` file, correct styles are being applied to your organisational chart.

```
"styles": [
    "src/styles.css",
    "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css",
    "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
    "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css"
],
```

See [this updated StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-organizationchart-demo-hbiutn?file=angular.json) for a working example, including the correct styles applied and a nice hierarchical structure in your browser output.

[image: StackBlitz outcome with styles]

### **Get started guide**

When digging further, it's even mentioned in the ['Get Started' guide of PrimeNG](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/setup).

> Dependencies
> Majority of PrimeNG components (95%) are native and there are some exceptions having 3rd party dependencies. In addition, components require PrimeIcons for icons.
>
> **The css dependencies are as follows, Prime Icons, theme of your choice and structural css of components.**

Here you have the option to include the styles via HTML references or via Angular CLI (as we did like above):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css" />
```

```
"styles": [
  "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
  "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css",
  "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
  //...
],
```